# CFNumber macro for constants

Tags: ios

Pretty sure the answer is No on this one, but it's painful enough I have to ask: Is there a CFNumber equivalent to CFString's CFSTR macro? To avoid this sort of thing:

```
char one = 1;
CFNumberRef cfONE = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberCharType, &one);
if (cfONE != NULL) {
    ... finally I can compare something to the number 1! ...
    CFRelease(cfONE);
} else {
    // not likely, but possible, if you really want to be conservative
}
```

Note that I'm *not* using Objective-C in this particular code.

Eric

Comment: Are you trying completely avoid Objective-C? I've written a few files that are 99% CF but dip into Foundation when it makes things easier.  In any case, you could consider setting up `cfOne` as a static variable that you initialize once, then it's an intentional leak you don't have to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using this function multiple times, you could the `static` modifier and stop worrying about deallocation:

```
static CFNumberRef cfONE = NULL;
if (cfONE == NULL) {
    static char one = 1;
    cfONE = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberCharType, &one);
    assert (cfONE != NULL); // Oh no, destroy the world!
}

//    ... finally I can compare something to the number 1! ...
```

So long as you have static, the static analyzer will leave you alone on the leak issue since it is an expected constant size memory allocation, `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` where `n` is the number of executions.

There are several ways to make this a macro.  I came up with this lazy one:

```
#define CFNUMDEF(name, type, numberType, value) \
static CFNumberRef name = NULL; \
if ( name == NULL) { \
    static type val = value ;\
    name = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, numberType , &val);\
    assert ( name != NULL); \
}

CFNUMDEF(cfONE, char, kCFNumberCharType, 1);
//    ... finally I can compare something to the number 1! ...
```

Comment: Thanks Brian - great idea about using static. I ended up essentially using your macro, but removed the type param, hard-coded it to an int, used kCFNumberIntType and called it CFNUM_INT.

Comment: Cool, forgot to move `kCFNumberCharType` to the macro signature.  Sticking with int is a good strategy.

Answer (score 1):

`CFSTR` is a little different from your case

> CFSTR() allows creation of compile-time constant CFStringRefs; the argument 
>   should be a constant C-string.
>
> CFSTR(), not being a "Copy" or "Create" function, does not return a new
>   reference for you. So, you should not release the return value. This is
>   much like constant C or Pascal strings --- when you use "hello world"
>   in a program, you do not free it.

Where as the object you create with `CFNumberCreate` will be owned by the caller so you may still want to keep the word `create` in the name to make this clear.

You could always make a helper function just to avoid passing the same arguments over and over

```
CFNumberRef PSNumberCreateWithChar(x)
{
  return CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberCharType, &x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but it's not the verbosity of the CFNumberCreate function I'd like to avoid, it's the whole process of creating and releasing the objects. A compile-time constant is exactly what I'd like, e.g. CFNUM(1). CFSTR is really __CFStringMakeConstantString(), and I don't see anything equivalent in the source for CFNumber. I guess I could make a CFNUM macro with the caveat that I'd still have to release the value.

Answer (score 0):

`CFNumberRef` and `NSNumber` are toll free bridged so you can use the `NSNumber` literal syntax and cast the result.

Comment: That requires Obj-C. This is all CF, not Foundation.

Comment: @EricMcNeill is there a reason you can't use Foundation? CF and F are pretty much indistinguishable these days from an implementation point-of-view.

Comment: Do you mean `static const CFNumberRef cfONE = (CFNumberRef)@1;`?  I'm still getting an _“error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant”_ with that.